# Strange Issue with Text Field Parser

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv

I have a strange issue when using the "Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser" in VB.NET.  I am creating a CSV file that uses ",*" as the delimiter and then trying to export that file into an EXCEL spreadsheet.  The program creates the file perfectly, but when I try to pull each entry from the file and put them into the Excel table, some of the entries are getting split up.  For example, one of the first entries in one of my rows is "H  WIRE*30(SHDR-30V&SHDR-30V)  160mm" without the quotes.  When I grab that entry using the TextFieldParser and export it into EXCEL, the 160mm gets dropped from the entry and its added to the row below.  See image. [Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8NEl.jpg)

Here is a link to the CSV that im using. [Test CSV Text File](http://www.filedropper.com/testcsv)

Here is the code.  (I removed the excel portion of the code for this post.) I put a message box in to show each entry the Parser is pulling.  When it gets to the "H  WIRE*30(SHDR-30V&SHDR-30V)  160mm" entry, it reads "H  WIRE*30(SHDR-30V&SHDR-30V)" as its own row with no entries after and then reads "160mm" as a new row with the remaining info that should be all together. (Sorry if that is confusing xD)

I just cant figure out why its doing this?  The CSV looks fine, and all the other rows read and export into excel perfectly.  But this same row, everytime, is messing up.

Thanks in advance for any help.

THANK YOU SO MUCH Idle_Mind.

```
Dim MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\TEST CSV.txt")
    MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.SetDelimiters(",*")
    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentField As String
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                MessageBox.Show(currentField)

            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unexpected Line Feed in that line.  I simply downloaded your text file, opened it in Notepad++, and turned on the View --> Show Symbol --> Show End of Line feature:
[image]